# Proving question is true with big o notation

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, asymptotics

I recently came across a big o question that I just can't understand. Now I know that $1 < \log n < n < n \log n < n^2$ and so on. But how would you prove this is true with the big o notation? In particular $1 < \log n$,  given the defintion of $1 = O(\log n)$. Any steps or tips to solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: I need to prove with big o notation to better understand the definitions and properties

Comment: Sorry I thought I misread your post. If $f(n) = O(g(n))$ you can only say that eventually $|f(n)| \leq M(g(n))$ for some positive number $M$. It doesn't tell you anything about the behavior everywhere, and it doesn't even tell you that $|f(n)| \leq g(n)$ eventually; it could be $M = 2$, for example.

Comment: Take for example $f(n) = n^2 + 2n$ and $g(n) = n^2$. We have $f(n) = O(g(n))$, since $|f(n)| \leq n^2 + 2n \leq n^2 + 2n^2 = 3n^2$ for large $n$, but $f(n) \geq g(n)$ for large $n$.

Comment: I could also be interpreting this problem incorrectly still. Are you trying to say that if a function is in $O(1)$ (equivalence class of functions which are asymptotic to $1$) then it is smaller than a function in $O(\log(n))$ eventually?

Comment: @User203940 Yes, sorry if it wasn't as clear as I intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f(n) \in O(1)$. There exists $N_0$ so that for all $n \geq N_0$, $|f(n)| \leq M_0$. Hence we have that $f$ is eventually a bounded function.

Now take $g(n) \in O(\log(n))$. This says that there exists an $N_1$ so that for all $n \geq N_1$, we have $|g(n)| \leq M_1 \log(n)$.

Here's an issue. We don't know what $f$ and $g$ look like. It could be that $g(n) \in O(1)$ as well, say $g(n) = M_1$, and $M_1 \geq M_0$. Then eventually we have $g(n) \geq |f(n)|$. On the other hand, what if $M_1 \leq M_0$ and $g(n) = M_1$? It still could be $g(n) \geq |f(n)|$, since all we know is an upper bound on $f$, or it could be eventually we have $f(n) = M_0$ so that $g(n) \leq f(n)$.

So we can't say anything about $f(n) \in O(1)$ and $g(n) \in O(\log(n))$ being such that $f(n) \leq g(n)$ or vice versa.

Maybe another way to interpret your problem is this, though. Is it true that $O(1) \subseteq O(\log(n))$? If $f(n) \in O(1)$, then there is some $N$ so that for all $n \geq N$ we have $|f(n)| \leq N$. Now for some $M$ we have that for all $n \geq M, N \leq N \log(n)$. If we take $N_1 = \max\{N,M\}$, then for all $n \geq N_1$ we have $|f(n)| \leq N \leq N\log(n)$ so that $f(n) \in O(\log(n))$.

Note this is a strict subset, since $\log(n) \in O(\log(n))$ but it unbounded so $\log(n) \notin O(1)$. We actually have $O(1) \subsetneq O(\log(n))$.

Maybe this is what you were wanting?

**Edit:** If you're just trying to prove the inequalities are true, the first follows by monotonicity of logarithm (meaning if $m \leq n$, then $\log(m) \leq \log(n)$). Note $\log(e) = 1$. Now for $n \geq 3$ (since $2 < e < 3$) we have $\log(n) > 1$.

For $\log(n) < n$, let's examine the function $f(x) = x - \log(x)$. We take its derivative, so $f'(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{x}$. It is $0$ when $x = 1$. For $x > 1$, it is positive (meaning increasing) and for $x < 1$ it is negative (meaning decreasing). So we know the difference is increasing for $x > 1$, and we know $f(e) = e - \log(e) = e - 1 > 0$, so for all $n \geq 3$ we have $n > \log(n)$. Using the fact that we have $\log(e) = 1$, and $n < n \log(n)$ for $n \geq 3$ again. Finally we know $\log(n) < n$ for $n \geq 3$, so $n \log(n) < n \cdot n = n^2$ for $n \geq 3$.

Notice I'm implicitly using the fact that if $f_1(n) \leq g_1(n)$ and $f_2(n) < g_2(n)$, then $f_1(n) f_2(n) < g_1(n) g_2(n)$. Make sure this makes sense.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up to your answer, since we can prove big-o by c = _ and n0 = _ we can show that T(n) <= c * f(n) for all n >= n0. Could we technically find a c and n0 to prove that 1 < logn ?

Comment: $\log(e) = 1$, logarithm is monotone, so for all integers $n \geq 3$ (since $2 < e < 3$) we have $1 < \log(n)$.